# Rails select and sort by aggregate of has_many

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sum

I have a Course model which has_many reviews. My Review model has a rating field. What I would like is a query to find the top rated courses. I want to do this in the SQL in order to avoid returning all the course objects and then trying to rank and sort them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't describe how you define "top rated". It could be that you want the courses with the highest individual ratings:

```
Course.joins(:reviews).group("courses.id").order("reviews.rating desc")
```

Or you might want the courses with the highest total ratings:

```
Course.joins(:reviews).group("courses.id").order("sum(reviews.rating) desc")
```

Then on each of these you can call `first(10)` to get the top ten by whichever criteria you want.

Comment: I actually wanted the highest average review so the second one is close but then I need to divide by the total to get the average. This seemed to work: ".order("sum(reviews.rating) / count(*)").

Comment: If you want the average you can probably do `.order("avg(reviews.rating)")`

Comment: 'avg', even better! Wish I could up vote this again. Do you know how to include Courses without any reviews? As it is now I only get those with reviews so I do a subsequent query to grab more.

Comment: If you use `Course.include(:reviews)` it should do an outer join which will pull in courses that have no reviews.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `includes` not `include`. So `Course.includes(:reviews)` etc.

Comment: Tried this: `Course.includes(:reviews).where('courses.ID IS NOT NULL').group('courses.id, reviews.id').order("avg(reviews.rating) desc")` but now it doesn't return the courses with reviews!

Comment: You shouldn't need the extra bits and bobs - just a straight swap of `joins` for `includes` should do it. If not it won't be a massive issue to do another query for a few courses to pad out the list.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work: `Course.includes(:reviews).group("courses.id, reviews.id").order("avg(reviews.rating) desc").limit(num)`. The reviews.id was necessary in the group clause.

Answer (score 2):

I would try this SQL:

```
SELECT courses.* FROM 
 (SELECT courses.*, count(*) as rating_no 
  FROM courses 
  JOIN reviews ON reviews.course_id = courses.id 
  GROUP BY reviews.course_id ) as res 
ORDER BY rating_no DESC
```

the idea:
You first take all data for each course, along with number of ratings. Then you just sort them. My experinece in MySQL is that GROUP BY and ORDER BY do not like each other, and that is why I used subquery. You might want to try on one query first though, but I doubt it will work :) If you are not interstend in just *number* of ratings, but for example actual average rate, you can make query like

```
SELECT courses.* FROM 
 (SELECT courses.*, (SUM(reviews.rating)/count(*)) as avg_rating 
  FROM courses 
  JOIN reviews ON reviews.course_id = courses.id 
  GROUP BY reviews.course_id HAVING count(*) > 0) as res 
ORDER BY rating_no DESC
```

having count(*) >0 is most likely not needed, but just in case I have added it, to point out that you should avoid dividing by 0.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about getting the average. I combined it with Shadwell's solution to get what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
select  * from courses where review=(select max(rating) from table)
```

or

```
select top 1.* from courses order by review desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`@courses =  Course.find(:all, :joins => "INNER JOIN reviews ON reviews.courses_id = courses.id", :order => "reviews.rating DESC")`

or RAW sql

```
`SELECT `courses`.* FROM `courses` INNER JOIN reviews ON reviews.courses_id = courses.id ORDER BY reviews.rating DESC`
```