# How to pull reviews from database and display in a gridview

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed a tutorial to build a Restaurant reviews site on Ruby on Rails and i adapted it for Hospitals.

I would like to display results from the database in a sorted format like highest reviews or highest number of reviews or by location (all available data in the database) in a gridview (limited to Top 6).

I am unsure as to where to even start , I know it might sound a but simple but i have researched and keep seeing so many options and got confused as to where to start.
Some solutions seem to fit small data sets but i fully expect this to grow exponentially in the future so the most effective way would be best for me.
I have SQLlite on my local environment and Postgres in my production environment.

This is what i have on my search page that displays all my Hospitals and what i have in my index page which displays all records in a grid. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**search.html.erb**

```
<div class="table-responsive table-box card"> 
  <%= form_tag search_hospitals_path, method: :get, class: "form-group" do %>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">Search and Review</div>
          <p>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],  class: "form-control formInput", placeholder: "Hospital Name" %>
          </p>
  </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="container hospital_display">
      <% @hospitals.each do |hospital| %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">                
              <%= link_to image_tag(hospital.image), hospital, class: "responsive" %>
            </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <%= link_to hospital.name, hospital %><br>
                  <%= hospital.address %><br>
                  <%= hospital.phone %><br>
                  <%= link_to hospital.website, hospital.website %>
                  <%# Checks for admin %>
                  <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
                    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_hospital_path(hospital), class: "btn btn-link" %>
                    <%= link_to 'Destroy', hospital, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-link" %>
                  <% end%>
                  <%# Rating %>
                  <% if hospital.reviews.count == 0 %>
                    No reviews yet, be the first to write one
                  <% elsif hospital.reviews.count == 1 %>
                  <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= hospital.avg_rating %> ></div>
                    1 Review
                  <% else %>
                  <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= hospital.avg_rating %> ></div>
                    <%= hospital.length %> <%= "Reviews" %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<script>
    $('.star-rating').raty({
        path: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/morafamedapp/stars',
        readOnly: true,
        score: function() {
            return $(this).attr('data-score');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have this on my index page
**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="jumboFluid">
<div class="jumbotron">
<section class="content">


<%= form_tag search_hospitals_path, method: :get, class: "form-group" do %>
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-addon">Search</div>
        <p>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],  class: "form-control formInput", placeholder: "Eye, Maternity" %>
          <%# <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
        </p>
</div>
  <% end %><br>



  <h3 class="intro2">Find the best HealthCare Options around you with Medapp.
  <br><%# Explore the best of healthcare available in your community.<br>
    Read and leave reviews to assist others seeking the best health care and keep our hospitals on their toes. %></h3>
</section>
</div>
</div>
<div class="hospitalList">
<h1 id="hospitalBanner">Hospitals</h1>
<blockquote> 
  <p class="text-center"><cite>&#8220;Explore the best of healthcare available in your community&#8221;</cite> </p>
</blockquote>

<% content_for(:body_attributes) do %>
    data-no-turbolink="false"
  <% end %>
<main>
<div class="container-fluid fluid">
<div class="row">
<% @hospitals.each do |hospital| %>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <%= link_to image_tag(hospital.image), hospital %>
        <div class="caption">
          <h4> <%= link_to hospital.name, hospital %></h4><br>
          <% if hospital.reviews.count == 0 %>
            0 Reviews
          <% elsif hospital.reviews.count == 1 %>
            <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= hospital.avg_rating %> ></div>
            1 Review
            <% else %>
            <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= hospital.avg_rating %> ></div>
            <%= hospital.length %> <%= "Reviews" %>
          <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
 </div>

</main>


<br>

<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
  <%= link_to 'New Hospital', new_hospital_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-special" %>
<% end %>

<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.$_Tawk = undefined;
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/592da976b3d02e11ecc677a1/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
s1.style.background = 'yellow';
})();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->

<script>
  $('.star-rating').raty({
    path: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/morafamedapp/stars',
    readOnly: true,
    score: function() {
      return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
  });
</script>

</div>
```

Hospitals_controller.rb

```
class HospitalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_hospital, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:search, :index, :show]
  before_action :check_user, except: [:search, :index, :show]
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  protect_from_forgery except: ["create"]

  def search
    if params[:search].present?
      @hospitals = Hospital.search(params[:search])
    else
      @hospitals = Hospital.all
    end
  end

  def import
   Hospital.import(params[:file])
  end


  # GET /hospitals
  # GET /hospitals.json
  def index
    @hospitals = Hospital.all
  end

  # GET /hospitals/1
  # GET /hospitals/1.json
  def show
    @reviews = Review.where(hospital_id: @hospital.id).order("created_at DESC")
    if @reviews.blank?
      @avg_rating = 0
    else
    @avg_rating = @reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
    end
  end

  # GET /hospitals/new
  def new
    @hospital = Hospital.new
  end

  # GET /hospitals/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /hospitals
  # POST /hospitals.json
  def create
    import if params[:file] # <= this here is the call to your import method

    @hospital = Hospital.new(hospital_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hospital.save
        format.html { redirect_to @hospital, notice: 'Hospital was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @hospital }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @hospital.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /hospitals/1
  # PATCH/PUT /hospitals/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @hospital.update(hospital_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @hospital, notice: 'Hospital was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @hospital }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @hospital.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /hospitals/1
  # DELETE /hospitals/1.json
  def destroy
    @hospital.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to hospitals_url, notice: 'Hospital was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_hospital
      @hospital = Hospital.find(params[:id])
    end

    def check_user
    unless current_user.admin?
        redirect_to root_url, alert: "Sorry, only admins can do that!"
    end
  end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def hospital_params
      params.require(:hospital).permit(:name, :address, :city_town, :state,  :phone, :website, :safe_care, :jci, :cohsasa, :best_known_4, :image )
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Hospital model, you could just define scopes that you can append to any query:

```
# app/models/hospital.rb
class Hospital < ActiveModel
  scope :order_by_highest_rated, -> { includes(:reviews).group("hospital_id").order("avg(reviews.rating) desc") }
  scope :order_by_most_reviews, -> { includes(:reviews).group("hospital_id").order("count(reviews.id) desc") }
end
```

then in your Hospital controller, you can add functionality to choose the sort order

```
class HospitalsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:search_by] == 'highest_ranked'
      @hospitals = Hospital.order_by_highest_rated
    else 
      @hospitals = Hospital.order_by_most_reviews
    end
  end
end
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16996960/2796616) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189390/rails-select-and-sort-by-aggregate-of-has-many?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for more readings

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. I have amended the question to include the controller.

Comment: Have you considered adding a reviews_count field and updating your belongs_to relationship to cached the count?

Comment: I would use `joins(:reviews)` instead of `includes(:reviews)`. This makes sure the table is always joined, whereas *includes* is more of a "chose the best solution for me" option. Since the `group("reviews.hospital_id")` and `order("avg(reviews.rating) desc")` both assume the table is joined I would make this an explicit join call.

Comment: Joins is an inner join, which would leave off hospitals that don’t have ratings,wouldn’t it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about accessing the value itself and only want the order I suggest going with [andrew21s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50479656/3982562). With that out of the way, let's get to my answer.

The question is simple enough although the answer is more complicated than you would expect. I assume the following associations in the models:

```
class Hospital < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews
end
```

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hospital
end
```

With the above present this issue can be solved with the following scopes:

```
class Hospital < ApplicationRecord

  # ...

  def self.include_review_count
    review_count = Review.select(Review.arel_table[:id].count)
                         .where(Review.arel_table[:hospital_id].eq(arel_table[:id]))
                         .as('review_count')

    select(*attribute_names.map(&:to_sym)).select(review_count)
  end

  def self.include_review_average
    review_average = Review.select(Review.arel_table[:rating].average)
                           .where(Review.arel_table[:hospital_id].eq(arel_table[:id]))
                           .as('review_average')

    select(*attribute_names.map(&:to_sym)).select(review_average)
  end

  # ...

end
```

With these scopes present you can now do the following in your controller:

```
class HospitalsController < ApplicationController

  # ...

  def index
    @hospitals = Hospital.include_review_count
                         .include_review_average
                         .order('review_count DESC', 'review_average DESC', :id)
                         .limit(6)
  end

  # ...

end
```

> **Note:** In the code above you can't use `.order(review_count: :desc, review_average: :desc, id: :asc)` because "review_count" is not a real attribute, but merely an alias. For this reason you'll have to use the literal (String) variant. The same is true when using this added attribute in a *where* statement. For example: `.where(review_count: 2)` doesn't work, whereas `.where('review_count = ?', 2)` does function.

This solution makes only one query and also allows you access the values without additional queries. An example could be (index.html.erb):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Review Count</th>
      <th>Review Average</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @hospitals.each do |hospital| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= hospital.id %></td>
        <td><%= hospital.name %></td>
        <td><%= hospital.review_count %></td>
        <td><%= hospital.review_average %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```